# How do I get the design view back?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017

I have seen a few questions about this but not one which is quite the same:

In Dev Studio 2017 I am writing a WinForms project.

At some point when I was coding I lost the ability to see the design view of the form.

See below, Form1 (the top one) only has the option to view the code, whereas Form2 has the ability to view the code or the design view.

Shift F7 has no effect and the Design View option does not appear in the right click menu.

[image]

How do I get the design view back?

Comment: Most likely due to `AlertDetails` type contained inside the same code file. Try moving it after `Form1` code.

Comment: Double click on the main form icon.   Right click is not used.

Comment: @IvanStoev, you are a king among men!  If you put that as an answer I will accept it etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design View option requires the code for the component to be designed to be either the only type, or *first* type inside the source code file.

In your case the code file contains a type `AlertDetails` which is before the `Form1` (which can be seen by the class view). Just move it to another code file or after `Form1` in the same file and the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of it you might have renamed the `Form1` *class* at some point or you have tried to copy and rename it to or from `AlertDetails`..

Your Form UI code is in a separate file from the main `Form` class, so you have to make sure that the class names match and is marked `partial class Your_Form_Name` in both/all files.

So lets assume your structure use to look like this:

[image]

***Form1.cs*** (1) is a *.cs* file on its own, but it is only one part of the complete `Form1` class.

In that file your class is defined like this: `public partial class Form1 : Form`

***Form1.Designer.cs*** (2) is also a *.cs* file on its own, but it also forms part of the `Form1` class.

The designer file defines the class like this: `partial class Form1`.

If you intended to rename `Form1` to `AlertDetails`, you have to make sure that the class name is the same in both *.cs* files, ***Form1.Designer.cs*** and ***Form1.cs***

So it should be

- `public partial class AlertDetails : Form` in the *Form1.cs* file
- and `partial class AlertDetails` in the *Form1.Designer.cs* file